# can matlab code be used in php?

Tags: php, matlab

I need to perform face detection operation using PHP. I have a source code in MATLAB. I do not have a clear idea about MATLAB. Is there any possibility to convert the MATLAB code to PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

No at present there does not exists any good known tool to do that and there is no popular demand for that as PHP is for different purpose and matlab is for different domain that rarely need to meet each other.

But for image processing in PHP i can refer you this link: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: can you please help me to perform face detection operation using PHP?

Comment: I am creating a POS software i need to identify the customer through camera. i need to detect the face of the customer and store them in my database and perform operations like 1. new customer addition 2.identification of the old customer. With the photo of the already existing customer i need to retrieve their details.

Comment: I created a pos software please help me